# Run Excel macro from different Excel file

Tags: python, win32com

I know there already are many questions regarding this topic, but I couldn't figure out a solution that works out for me.

I want to run an Excel macro stored in an 'xlsm' file, but I need to run it on a different Excel file ('xlsx').

Whenever I try the code below, I get an error message saying that the macro wasn't found, so I suppose the problem has to do with the pathing.

This is what I have:

```
import win32com.client
import os

try:
    excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel_path = r'C:\Users\martin\Desktop\testing_excel.xlsx'
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_path, ReadOnly=1)
    excel.Application.Run("'macro_testing.xlsm'!local_macro")
    workbook.Save()
    excel.Quit()
    print('Macro run succesfully')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    excel.Quit()
```

The 'xlsm' file with the macro is named 'macro_testing.xlsm', and the macro name is 'local_macro'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note, the macro has to be able to process (work with) different excel file. i.e. completion of the task would depend also on how the macro is written.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody there who was experiencing the same problem I had, what I finally did was open the two Excel files, like this:

```
import os

excel_path = os.path.abspath('Excel_to_run_macro.xlsx')

if os.path.exists(excel_path):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('Excel_with_macro.xlsm'), ReadOnly=1)
    workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(excel_path, ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("'Excel_with_macro.xlsm'!Macro_name")
    workbook.Save()
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do similar, I store the macro in a command book (.xlsm) - or even .xlam that is called from the command book (which is .xlsm) and it then opens, manipulates, saves and closes .xlsx as appropriate.

If you try to run it from within an .xlsx, you'll never be able to save the code that has done the run, not exactly advisable for repetitive workflows.

So,

macro_testing.xlsm could have another sub which would be something like:

```
sub runExternal()

    with Sheets("Sheet1").
        extPath = cells(1,2)  
        extBook = cells(2,2)
        'Declaring the path & workbook to use within the master workbook's "Sheet1"

    workbooks.open(extPath & extBook) ReadOnly:False

    call local_macro()

    application.displayalerts = false  'Just in case there are any GUI prompts
    workbooks(extBook).close saveChanges:=True
    application.displayalerts = true

end sub
```

Comment: Hi @Amiga500! The problem is right now I'm doing tests with a dummy Excel, but I won't be able to alter the final macro. Ideally, I should be able to run the macro in a different Excel file, and repeat the process many times

Comment: I just used the local declarations of extPath & extBook as an example, normally I would have read them off a worksheet cell. So if that was your sole concern, after that modification the macro would remain unchanged for real use. Not sure if that helps you or not? Tweaked answer for that.

Comment: Another option (which I did mention kinda as a footnote), is the .xlam - have you ever used them before? It'd mean the macros are stored as add-ins, so always available to your excel instance - regardless of what workbooks you have open.

Comment: What I finally did was open the two Excels, this way I could access the macro (I supposed the macro would apply to the last opened Excel). In any case, the '.xlam' option seems very interesting! I'll try it out. Thanks a lot!!